# Number of distinct paths between a point a 2D plane and the origin of the plane

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, 2d, polynomial-math

Suppose, I am at the origin of a 2D plane. I want to reach point(x,y) by making **exactly N** steps.

If I am currently at point (p,q) then, I can go to points (p+1,q), (p,q+1), (p-1,q), (p,q-1) after one step.

How many different routes can I use to do that? Note that : **N will be at most 10 million** .

Comment: Are there any other restrictions? Can only visit a point once? Have to stay in the positive quadrant?

Comment: No, no other constrains. Can visit one point more than one time and all 4 quadrants are accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New answer here:**
After analysis of the calculated tables - it is possible to find number of paths with some combinatorics.

Delphi code (note that long arithmetics should be used for big numbers beyond Int64 range):

```
function PathCount(x, y, N: Integer): Int64;
var
  t, Diff: Integer;
begin
  x := Abs(x); //exploit symmetry
  y := Abs(y);

  if y > x then begin  //Swap them for simplicity, exploit symmetry again
    t := x;
    x := y;
    y := t;
  end;

  Diff := N - (x + y);
  if (Diff < 0) or Odd(Diff) then
    Exit(0);  //return 0 for unavailable points

  Diff := Diff div 2;
  Result := CombinationCount(N, x + Diff) * CombinationCount(N, Diff);
end;


function CombinationCount(n, k: Integer): Int64;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 1;
  if k > n - k then
    k := n - k;
  for i := 1 to k do
    Result := (Result * (n - i + 1)) div i;
end;
```

---

*Old answer (for demonstration)*

For reasonable N it is possible to use  dynamic programming. Make 3d-array with limits (-N/2..N/2),(-N/2..N/2),(0..N). Remember that its size is N^3 (10^21 for 10 million points, impractical). You can exploit symmetry, but reducing factor is small constant only (2 or 4).

Recursive formula:

```
P(p, q, K) = P(p-1, q, K-1) + P(p+1, q, K-1) + P(p, q-1, K-1) + P(p, q+1, K-1)
```

Fill array layer by layer: at the first step make P(x-1,y0,1) = 1 (and 3 points more) and so on... 
Neighbourhood of the inital point after 0, 1 and 2 steps:

```
                  0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0    0 1 0   0 2 0 2 0
0 1 0    1 0 1   1 0 4 0 1
0 0 0    0 1 0   0 2 0 2 0
                  0 0 1 0 0
```

6 steps animated:

[image]

After the finish, P(0, 0, N) will contain number of paths.

**P.S.** Probably, there is some combinatorial formula. For example, we can see binomial coefficients C(N,K) in the last diagonals (1 2 1, 1 3 3 1, 1 4 6 4 1 ...), next non-zero diagonal contains N * C(N,K) an so on.

Comment: Even if I exploit symmetry, the memory complexity will still be huge, isn't it?

Comment: Something is off with the new addition.  `x=y=0` returns 0 or 1.

Comment: @Teepeemm x=y=0 returns 0 for odd N steps and non-zero value for even N

Comment: You're right; I was overlooking `div 2`.  Can you give an explanation for how `C(N,(N+x-y)/2)*C(N,(N-x-y)/2)` gives the right answer?  I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @Teepeemm I haven't found worthy concise explanation yet (except for x+y=N case)